# Upper function converting special language characters to english words in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, uppercase

I have to use upper function to convert a value in upper case. Value contains special characters as shown: GothaER Straße KAISTRAßE HØJBRO plads QUAI À LA Chaux. Upper function is converting value in upper but converting special characters to other value. Like it's converting  ß to ss etc.. How can I get an output in upper and still holds special character values?

Like expected value of UPPER('Straße') is STRAßE.